# Using batch file, open virtual box, restore to the snapshot specified and open the snapshot image

Tags: batch-file, virtualbox, restore, snapshot

The following code in the batch file opens the virtual box "VMWINDOWS7" and runs the latest snapshot in the virtual box

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" startvm "VMWINDOWS7"
```

If I have to restore the current state to a particular snapshot that is already saved what command should I add to the code. Will it be similar to the following?

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" startvm "VMWINDOWS7" restore "SnapShot1"
```

Also upon opening, the username and password of the image "SnapShot1" need to be provided through the script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To Restore to a snapshot through the virtualbox command line use the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" snapshot "VMWINDOWS7" restore "SnapShot1"
```

I am not sure what you mean when you say... 
"Also upon opening, the username and password of the image "SnapShot1" need to be provided through the script."

If you want to start your VM headless you can use:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" startvm "VMWINDOWS7" -type headless
```

Once the VM is running then you can remote into the VM using [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) ([found here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)) to run the commands you would like.

```
Psexec \\VMWINDOWS7 -u username -p password C:\MyScriptToRun.bat
```

For all information on virtualbox command line usage. [View here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/)